# Allow network trafficn over Umbrella vpn to host, not allowing

Tags: cisco-vpn

I try to direct all network access sharing to host but keeps reporting network error.

Here are the last logs:

```
insertId,labels.tunnel_id,logName,receiveLocation,receiveTimestamp,resource.labels.gateway_id,resource.labels.project_id,resource.labels.region,resource.type,severity,textPayload,timestamp
1htz87kf15cmyg,8052204792771793104,projects/single-planet-281907/logs/cloud.googleapis.com%2Fipsec_events,,2023-12-08T08:02:10.684420540Z,4981033666932361119,single-planet-281907,us-central1,vpn_gateway,DEBUG,"establishing IKE_SA failed, peer not responding",2023-12-08T08:02:10.603478501Z
1htz87kf15cmyf,8052204792771793104,projects/single-planet-281907/logs/cloud.googleapis.com%2Fipsec_events,,2023-12-08T08:02:10.684420540Z,4981033666932361119,single-planet-281907,us-central1,vpn_gateway,DEBUG,giving up after 5 retransmits,2023-12-08T08:02:10.603370051Z
```

Comment: Your peer is not responding. Is the services running, and is it accessible?